# How to make a library linkable with g++ -l argument

Tags: libraries, g++

How can I make a shared library which is in `/usr/lib/some-path` linkable with the g++ `-l` argument when compiling?

As far as I know, to do what I want, I need to `chmod 0755` the library `.so` file, create some kind of a link file and I need to update the library cache. I tried using `ldconfig` command and it worked, but not for the subdirectories of `/usr/lib`. I also tried `ln -s /usr/lib/some-path/libmy.so /link/file/output/dir` which created a link file, but g++ still couldn't find the library with the `-lmy`. I tied running `ldconfig` after `ln` but that did not work.

Comment: Just to clear any possible confusion here: by "creating a link" do you mean creating a symlink to the library in another location or do you mean linking against it during compilation?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using `ldconfig` for this? You should use `ln`:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/src-con/your_library /path/to/target
```

where `/path/to/target` is where you want to create the link.

**Update**

In light of your edits, I believe what you want is

```
g++ ... -L /usr/lib/some-path -l my ...
```

From the output of `g++ -v --help`:

> **-L DIRECTORY, --library-path DIRECTORY**
>        Add DIRECTORY to library search path

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html this is the reason why I use `ldconfig`. Step 4 "Using ldconfig to modify ld.so"

Comment: And sorry for accepting your answer too early. This command line created the link, but for some reason, when I linked the library in a makefile like this `-lmylib`, g++ couldn't find it. I tried creating the link in the same subdirectory and in `/usr/lib`.

Comment: I absolutely remade my question, because I was unconscious when I was writing it the first time. :)

Comment: @VitaliusKuchalskis Please see the update.

Comment: No, I need the library to be linkable simply by adding -lmy to the g++ command line.

Comment: @VitaliusKuchalskis Have you tried symlinking the library in `/usr/lib/` instead of the object file output directory? Also, that requirement isn't clear from your question. Could you please add it to the question text?